# Partitioning MySQL table column

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I want to create the table in MySQL with the partitioning like below

```
CREATE TABLE `ccd` (
  `Created Month` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Employee Organization Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Employee Login` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Service Request #` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` longtext)
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

PARTITION BY RANGE (SUBSTRING(`Created Month`,1,4)  )

(PARTITION sp0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2010') ENGINE = MyISAM,

 PARTITION sp1 VALUES LESS THAN   ('2012' ) ENGINE = MyISAM,

 PARTITION sp2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014' ) ENGINE = MyISAM

);
```

In the  table , `Created Month` column will be having the values like

```
Created Month
2011 / 02
2011 / 06
2012 / 02
2013 / 01
2013 / 02
2013 / 05
2013 / 05
```

When i'm trying to run the statement, i'm getting the error message like

```
ERROR: This partition function is not allowed
Error Code: 1564
```

Anyone tell me, where i'm making the mistake..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all functions are allowed to be used in the data partitioning rule, as you can imagine `SUBSTRING` is one of them.

[List of allowed functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html)

Solution:

Change `Created Month` from `varchar` to `date` and then use :
   - `PARTITION BY RANGE (MONTH(Created Month)  )`

Comment: @CarlJohn : np, also i've posted a solution that you can try out